# How to permanently fix position of a div inside absolute div or how to use overflow hidden outside of a div

Tags: css, css-position

I want to transform on hover **.div1** absolute div but **.div2** will be fix at the same position. I don't want to use transform for **.div2**, because of lag.

**Without Fix Position**
[image: Without Fix Position (Example Image)]

**What i want (Fixed Position)**
[image: What i want (Example Image)]

If this is not possible, then there anyway to use overflow hidden outside the div?

**Codepen -** https://codepen.io/Ayan90510/pen/xxEwdQV

**CSS & HTML**

```css
.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ffc107;
  top: 70px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translate(0);
  overflow: hidden
}
.div2 {
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: #dc3545;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position:  relative;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5);
}  

.div1:hover {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px);
}   

.div1:hover .div2 {
  /*transform: translate(-50px, -50px);*/
{
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: your first idea to set opposite translate value is fine , you could use CSS var to easily update the vaues : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/RwGWZPO (fixed won't help)